# HTML input tag of type file not fully showing

Tags: html, css, input

I have the following HTML code which doesn't fully show the button that I am trying to display and I don't know why. The button works fine it just seems to not fit.

Here is an image of how the tag looks:

[image]

```html
<div>
  <input title="ChoosePhoto" type="file" id="addfoto0" onchange="pressed(0)" />
</div>
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour] first. Then 
read [how to ask questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After 
that edit the question to meet the guidelines and provide 
a [repro] for debugging details. The code you provided does not reproduce the issue you describe!

Comment: CHec parent container width or any other CSS which restrict the width